# How to mock implementation of an inner function?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I want to use jest to mock the implementation of an inner function. Can anyone help?

Now the result is inner but I want mock.

-----------------index.js-----------------

```
let mainFn = ()=>{
    return innerFn();
}

let innerFn = ()=>{
    return 'inner';
}

module.exports = {mainFn, innerFn};
```

-------------------index.test.js-----------------

```
let index = require('./index.js');

test('test', () => {
    index.innerFn = jest.fn().mockImplementation(()=>{return 'mock'});
    let result = index.mainFn();
    expect(result).toBe('mock');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should extract your inner function to a separate file (module). Then you can mock it easily:

```
jest.mock('./innerFn.js')
```

or for example:

```
jest.mock('./innerFn.js', () => 'mock')
```

Comment: Yes I think this is the easiest solution. Thanks